# How to say with?

Tags: particle-と

I want to say "I drank coffee WITH Harukaさん at Starbucks"

Is と the particle you use for "with"?

> 私はスターバックスでHarukaさんWITHコーヒーをのみました。

If use と here doesn't that mean "I drank Haruka and coffee at Starbucks"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd say

> 私はスターバックスでハルカさん**と**コーヒーをのみました。

to mean "I drank coffee with Haruka-san at Starbucks."

You'd say

> 私はスターバックスで紅茶**と**コーヒーをのみました。

to mean "I drank tea and coffee at Starbucks."

Comment: You can also say 私はハルカさんとスターバックスでコーヒーをのみました。 or 私はスターバックスでハルカさんと一緒にコーヒーをのみました。

Comment: Ok thanks. So the meaning of と is based on context. In the first sentence と used with a person means "with". In the second sentence it means "and".

Comment: Unfortunately, You couldn't solve the ambiguity by "person" or "thing". Think of 「化{ば}け物{もの}がハルカさんとブロッコリーを食べました」, here you can't decide if the monster ate broccoli **with** Haruka like in _Beauty and the Beast_, or just ate broccoli **and** Haruka. It all depends on common sense that you never "drink Haruka".